# Computing derivative wrt to the input of a network with batchnormalization : training vs inference time

Tags: tensorflow

I am noticing a different behavior when I try to compute the derivative of a network output with respect to its input when this network has a Batch Normalization layer.

More specifficaly the derivative are equal to 0 when setting training = True, which I think shouldn't be the case.
At inference time the behavior is as I expected. See the code below :

```
import tensorflow as tf


x =tf.constant([[1.],[2.],[3.]])


class model_bn(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super(model_bn, self).__init__()
    # I am setting the momentum to 0 so that batch mean and variance are equal to moving mean and variance
    self.batchnorm0 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=(1,), axis = 1, momentum=0.00, center = False, scale = False)       

  def call(self, inputs):   
    x = inputs
    x = self.batchnorm0(x)
    return 10.*x


model = model_bn()

# Computing the derivative at training time
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch((x))
    # calling the model with training = True implies that the moving mean and variance are computed
    y = model(x, training = True)    
y_x = tape.gradient(y, x)


print(model.batchnorm0.moving_mean, model.batchnorm0.moving_variance)
print(y, y_x)   # y_x = [[0.], [0.], [0.]]


# Computing the derivative at inference time
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch((x))
    y = model(x, training = False)    # with training = False we use the moving mean and variance instead of the batch mean and variance but here with momentum = 0.00 they should be the same
    # y = tf.reshape(y[:,0],(y.shape[0],1))
y_x = tape.gradient(y, x)

print(y, y_x)
```

I would expect in both cases that the derivative would be equal to :

10./sqrt(var +  epsilon)

where var is either the moving variance or the batch variance (which I think should be the same here) and epsilon is a constant set to 0.001 by default.

What I am missing here?